# What is the reputation of Schuon in the Perennial Philosophy or Philosophy of Religon?

Tags: philosophy-of-religion

I've just come across the writings of Fritjof Schuon and they appear to be impressive. There is a hint of new-ageism about him, and having never heard of him before I have no idea of his general reputation apart from his wikipedia page. What exactly is his reputation within academic circles?

Comment: But this raises another interesting question. Let us assume that religious truth is something objective, and that is ultimately what any human being is after. Then, to what extent is the reputation of a given philosopher in any given circle, a correct measure or gauge to how close that philosopher is to objective religious truth?

Comment: Sure. But it is something to navigate by, whether one chooses to accept that collective opinion, or reject it.

Comment: It's worth noting that Schuon is apparently a relatively minor figure within one branch of the Perennial Philosophy school of thought --so the title of this question and the question itself are not well-matched.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perennial_philosophy

Comment: @Chris sunami: good point, the first hint that I had of the Perennial Philosophy was via Tagore, but he never named it as such; whereas Schuon had, hence the question - but I see from your ref now, it goes quite a bit further back.

Comment: I know this is an older question, but it might be worth retitling this one after Schuon (since that matches the answer you received), and asking about the Perennial Philosophy in general in a separate question if it still interests you.,

Comment: @chris sunami: I've gone along with your suggestion; perennial philosophy still interests me, not so sure about Schuon.  Interestingly the wiki article  mentions Karen Armstrong as a perennialist.

Answer (score 3):

> What exactly is his reputation within academic circles?

Well, it's hard to prove a negative, so let's just say this: he fails to appear in the Routledge Encyclopedia of Philosophy, an almost 10,000 page reference work.

As a point of comparison, we can point out that the REP includes 3 pages on Anna Maria van Schurman, who was (apparently) *"among the few women to publish views on 
Counter-Reformation controversies concerning predestination and transubstantiation. Her autobiography served as an apology for the Pietist sect, Labadism."*

In fact, it appears to be rather hard to come by any information on Schuon that was not published by his own press; one of the few independent reports I found was a [report](http://books.google.no/books?id=GcUFmQ-NF_0C&pg=PA175&lpg=PA175#v=onepage&q&f=false) of cult-like behavior, and charges (later dropped) of sexual abuse of minors.